# study comedy "at" or "in" the XYZ theater

Tags: grammar, prepositions, at-in

> I will study comedy at XYZ theater

Sounds more intuitive.

Which one is grammatically correct and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you perceive the XXX Theater. If you're talking about the building, occupied by the XXX Theater, then you should use *in* - *I will study comedy in the [building of] XXX Theater*. Same as *I will study comedy inside the XXX Theater*

If you're talking about XXX Theater as a whole, then *at* would indeed be correct. *I will study comedy at the XXX Theater*.

Comment: A good explanation. The same kudos to @Ham and Bacon for a elaborate explanation. thanks

Answer (score 3):

"At" is more correct

The same reason why we don't say: "Have dinner in my house.", but rather "Have dinner at my house."

The reason "at" is used is because "in" refers specifically to within the building, whereas "at" refers to the building and its vicinity.

That's why we say " I'm *at* the station *in* New York."

You are in the vicinity of the station, but you are within New York.

So you study at XXX theatre, as well as its vicinity, i.e. it's smaller buildings and offices surrounding it, but you aren't necessarily studying only when you are inside the theatre itself.